# Querying Postgres from Grails MVC application

Tags: postgresql, grails, grails-orm

- Configured Datasource.groovy and BuildConfig.groovy
- need help to query Postgres database in groovy service.

Having a following table in postgres :
[table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubkSM.jpg)

Needs to write the following SQL query in grails application :

```
SELECT json_agg(r)
FROM(
SELECT data#>'{"name"}' as program,data#>'{"country"}' as agency,sum(cast(cast(data#>'{"amount"}' as text)as Integer)) as total_amount 
 FROM salary 
 group by data#>'{"name"}',data#>'{"country"}'
 order by program, agency
)r
```

Comment: Need to query JSONB data from the postgres based on the filtering conditions, or we can say needs to migrate from mongodb to postgres using the following schema corresponding to a mongo colllection : id, data (jsonb datatype). not sure whether i explained my point clearly..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used the following code and it works...

```
DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/TestDb");
dataSource.setUsername("postgres");
dataSource.setPassword("password");
def sql = new Sql(dataSource)
def resultRows = sql.rows(---SQL Query here---)
return resultRows
```

need help to replace above JDBC method with Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I can't comment yet because I don't have 50 reputations, so I leave my comment here. 
Have you tried to create view using CREATE VIEW in postgres and use simple query from your service? That's what I did with mine. It was much easier to query that way from grails.

**EDIT - My SQL Service example**

```
package com.myApp

import groovy.sql.Sql  //Need to import this 

class SomeService {

    def dataSource //Need it to connect to your database

    def result() {

        def sql = new Sql(dataSource)

        def resultRows = sql.rows('...your SQL statement...')
    }
}


package com.myApp

class SomeController {

    def someService  //Inject your serivce here

    def resultRows = someService.result()  //Call service method here
    [resultRows:resultRows]  //Put the result into a map

}
```

And you can call your result map from your view.

Now, if you don't want your long SQL statement inside your service, you can use CREATE VIEW sql statement inside your postgres.

```
CREATE or REPLACE VIEW result_table as
        (... your SQL statement...);
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but we need to write the data querying logic in the grails code itself, please suggest if we can do it that way, or can you just provide the lines of code to access data from view...

Comment: @shubham, I've included my example.